# How to start Ubuntu in GUI mode

Tags: boot, 17.10, live-usb

Recently I started Kali from live USB. After that my computer starts only in console mode. What should I do to enter in usual GUI mode?

I have Ubuntu 17.10

P.S. I new to linux so, please, explain as simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

I've found decision by installing ubuntu-desktop. I'll be grateful, if somebody explain me, how can I lose this package after booting from live usb.

P.S. Sorry for that question, I didn't try to solve the problem enough before I post it

Comment: Usually using a live USB will not touch your hard drive or existing installation on it. Perhaps you intentionally or unintentionally modified or deleted  some if the files of the Ubuntu installation on the drive ?